# Proving an inequality about hitting time of a Markov chain

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory

Q) Let $T_C = \text{inf}\{n\geq 1:X_n\in C\}$. Suppose that $S-C$ is finite and for each $x\in S-C$, $P_x(T_C<\infty)>0$. Show that there is an $N<\infty$ and $\epsilon>0$ s.t. for all $x\in S-C, P_x(T_C>kN)\leq (1-\epsilon)^k$.

Couple of questions to make sure I am using the hypothesis of the question correctly.

$1$) Since $P_x(T_C<\infty)>0$, does that mean $\exists$ $N_x$ for each $x\in S-C$ s.t. $P_x(T_C<N_x)>0$?

$2$) Since $S-C$ is finite, there exists an $N=\underset{x\in S-C}{\text{max}}N_x$?

If the above are true, I can take $\epsilon=\text{min}_xP(T_C<N)$ and

$$P_x(T_C>kN)= P_x(T_C\circ \theta_{(k-1)N}>N;1_{\{T_C>(k-1)N\}}) = E_x(E_x(1_{\{T_C\circ \theta_{(k-1)N}>N\}}|\mathcal{F}_{\{(k-1)N\}});1_{\{T_C>(k-1)N\}}) = P_{X_{(k-1)N}}(T_C>N)P_x(T_C>(k-1)N)\leq (1-\epsilon).P_x(T_C>(k-1)N)$$

and the answer follows by induction. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) and 2) are both correct. 1) follows from the fact $(T_C <\infty)=\bigcup_N (T_C <N)$.